# How to exit from foreach loop? Which using enum data

Tags: java, loops

I wanted to implement a game with levels and after winning the current level, the user can solve another one. I did it by for each loop using enum data. If you have a another way of solving this problem, please share with me. Program already changes levels after right decision from user, but I want to implement that if user provides a wrong answer, it exits from main loop. I tried to solve it with the `break` operator, but it doesn't work. If you have another solution to this problem, please share with me.

```
static void levelchanger() {
    Levelinfo[] types = Levelinfo.values();
    for (Levelinfo arr : types) {
        while (arr.moves != 0 && arr.display != arr.goal) {
            System.out.println("It is " + arr + " level. You have: " + arr.moves + " moves. Goal: " + arr.goal);
            System.out.println("Step: 1) " + arr.gnumbers[0] + " 2) " + arr.gnumbers[1]);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int action = in.nextInt();
            switch (action) {
            case 1:
                arr.display += arr.gnumbers[0];
                System.out.println("Result: " + arr.display);
                break;
            case 2:
                arr.display += arr.gnumbers[1];
                System.out.println("Result: " + arr.display);
                break;
            }
            arr.moves--;
            if (arr.moves == 0 && arr.display != arr.goal) {
                System.out.println("You don't have more moves!");
                break;
            } else if (arr.display == arr.goal) {
                System.out.println("Alright! Next level");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I tried to solve it with break operator"* and what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add tag to the loop

```
a: for (;;)
   {
     while()
     {
      if(condition)
        break a;// at your condition  write like this
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement will only break out of the current loop.

You can either change your break to a `return` if there is nothing else you want to do after the `for`, or restructure your code to make use of smaller methods, so that you avoid so much nesting within one method.

You can also add a boolean variable which is set to false, and checked in the for loop but will probably make the code dirtier.